# Should maintaining neutral sitting posture be tiring for someone trying to fix anterior pelvic tilt?

Tags: back-pain, posture

I have a significant anterior pelvic tilt, which is problematic because it has resulted in lower backpain.

I've decided to fix this problem by doing the necessary exercises and maintain a good sitting posture.

However, maintaining neutral sitting posture is quite tiring because my core muscles are contracted, should this be the case?

Comment: Are your lats really strong? E.g. lots of pullups and lat pull downs? I am wondering about the same question, but I don't fully "get it".

Answer (score 2):

### Anterior Pelvic Tilt vs Innominate Torsion

How exactly was it determined you have an **anterior pelvic tilt** *(symmetrically bilateral tilt)* vs an **innomate torsion** *(R) vs (L) asymmetrical tilt?*

- ASIS Palpation? Clinical Testing?
- Does a LLD exist *(if so True or Functional)*?
- *Any Frontal Plane Deviations?*
- *Neuromusclar Involvement?*
- *Knee Alignment (Genu Valgum vs Varum)  Any Pain?*
- Any secondary contributing factors?

---

> "I've decided to fix this problem by doing the necessary exercises and
>   maintain a good sitting posture."

---

It's not that simple.  You first need to figure out what the exact issue(s) are and what tests will rule in / rule out the possible contributing factors.

For example -- Without knowing these answers, you can end up treating a neuromuscular issue *(such as incorrect muscle firing patterns)* presenting as Lower Back Pain (LBP) by stretching your hamstrings.

---

### Pain and Dysfunctional Movement

> “Exercise of the core musculature is more than trunk strengthening. 
>   In fact, **motor relearning of inhibited muscles may be more important
>   than strengthening in patients with LBP"**

---

> "**Poor movement can exist anywhere in the body poor movement patterns
>   can only exist in the brain.**  Pain attenuated movement patterns may
>   lead to protective movement and fear of movement, resulting in
>   clinically observed impairments such as decreased ROM, muscle length
>   changes, declines in strength, and ultimately contribute to the
>   resultant disability.”

---

### Kinematic Relationships

Some pictures that show the chain of muscular imbalances associated with pelvic dysfunction.

---

### Pelvic and LE

[image]

---

### An Innominate Torsion with a Lateral Lumbar Deviation.

---

[image]

---

### Basic Imbalances

[image]

---

### Bottom Line

Proper testing is required to understand what is happening.  Without this an accurate treatment plan cannot be developed.

---

**Sources:**

1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3364068/
2. http://www.pelinks4u.org/bookreviews/media_1011.htm
3. http://www.profedf.ufpr.br/rodackibiomecanica_arquivos/Books/Duane%20Knudson-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Biomechanics%202ed.pdf
4. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4060319/
5. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4127517/

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be the case.

Anterior pelvic tilt basically means that your hips are tilted forward, because of this your entire spine is tilted.

Your hip flexors are probably shortened which causes your pelvis to tilt, if you maintain a neutral posture this will be harder on your muscles because they are essentially stertching at that point. So yes, you will get tired from it and might even get sore muscles around your hips and lower back.

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer - where are you stretching when you straighten the spine?  Your hip flexors are shortened while sitting, so it's not like you are stretching them out. It seems like it would be the case if one's abs were weak (just counter-acting erector spinae and lats).

Comment: They are shortened while sitting, so they are on stretch while standing up straight is what my answer is saying. Is that not the exact same thing as you just said?

Answer (score 0):

Sitting in general is pure poison for the spine (search online for 'Sitting is the new smoking') 
For the 'necessary exercises' you should actually consider a well balanced training plan including ALL parts of the body with equal emphasis on all areas. 
By focusing mainly on the affected area in your routine you are merely shifting imbalances from one area to another. 
The tiring core muscles are the best example for an imbalance. Your body is hereby sending you a clear message in bold, bright letters. 
My personal advice to you is: 
**Get in tune with your body**. 
It is constantly communicating with you, telling you every detail you need to know but in a language you don't understand yet. LEARN IT!
**MIX IT UP**
Aim to keep the periods in a seated position very short. 
Stand up, stretch and move around as often as possible.
Switch seating positions often.
**Play it out!** 
Engage different muscle groups while seated, contract, hold, release. Challenge yourself on the time you can hold the contraction.
Or even skip the chair completely on occasion, remaining in a squat position (in front of your workspace) as long as possible.

Be kind to your body and it will be kind to you.
All the best to you!